# Password being sent in cleartext in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, restful-authentication

In my application i am using restful authentication for authenticating login. But the problem is whenever i login and check the logs, my password is sent in cleartext and it is easily readable. I tried many things but still the issue exists.

Any idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

In application.rb just add the following line, the remaining will be taken care;

```
config.filter_parameters << :password
```